# replacing all NA with a 0 in data.table in R

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a `data.table` with many columns. There are 4 columns where I want to replace `NA` with an 0.

I have a working solution:

```
  claimsMonthly[is.na(claim9month),claim9month := 0
          ][is.na(claim10month),claim10month := 0
            ][is.na(claim11month),claim11month := 0
              ][is.na(claim12month),claim12month := 0]
```

However, this is quite repetitive and I wanted to reduce this by using an loop (not sure if that is the smartest idea though?):

```
  for (i in 9:12){
    claimsMonthly[is.na(paste0("claim", i, "month")), paste0("claim", i, "month") := 0]
  }
```

When I run this loop nothing happens. I guess it is due to the pact that the `paste0()` returns `"claim12month"`, so I get `in.na("claim12month")`. The result of that is `FALSE` despite the fact that there are `NA` in my data. I guess this has something to do with the quotes?

This is not the first time i have issues with using `paste0()` or running loops with `data.table`, so I must be missing something important here.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can either specify the `.SDcols` with the names of the columns ('nm1'), loop over the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table) and assign the NA to 0 (`replace_na` from `tidyr`)

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
nm1 <- paste0("claim", 9:12, "month")
setDT(claimsMonthly)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, replace_na, 0), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Or as @jangorecki mentioned in the comments, `nafill` from `data.table` would be better

```
setDT(claimsMonthly)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, nafill, fill = 0), .SDcols = nm1]
```

---

or using a loop with `set`, assign the columns of interest with 0 based on the NA values in each column by specifying the `i` (for row index) and `j` for column index/name

```
for(j in nm1){
    set(claimsMonthly, i = which(is.na(claimsMonthly[[j]])), j =j, value = 0)
 }
```

Or with `setnafill`

```
setnafill(claimsMonthly, cols = nm1, fill = 0)
```

Comment: note that `setnafill` eliminate the need for `[` and reduce number of copies to zero

Comment: both will compute columns in parallel

Comment: @jangorecki sure, I will.  Let me first try from my end and check if I cannot possibly solve it by myself :=)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
claimsMonthly[, 9:12][is.na(claimsMonthly[, 9:12])] <- 0
```

Also you can use variable names:

```
claimsMonthly[c("claim9month", "claim10month","claim11month","claim12month")][is.na(claimsMonthly[c("claim9month", "claim10month","claim11month","claim12month")])] <- 0
```

Or even better you can use a vector with all variables with "claimXXmonth" pattern.